# How to control the number of times my detail section repeats in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, basic

I have a VB/Crystal reports business card application that I'm maintaining.

how do I change the number of detail section repetitions from 10 to 8.  I've been looking for several hours and can't find it?

currently it prints 8 on the first page, and 2 on the 2nd, which is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Details section >> Select Section Expert >> under Paging Tab you can control your section... you can review the below link :

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3530837

Comment: hmm... I can supress it, but the last 2 sets still inspire a blank second page to be printed.  I can instruct my printer not to print the second page, but not sure he will always remember.